# How to use calcite cassandra adapters in application

Tags: apache-calcite

Are there some examples about calcite cassandra adapters in java code? there are only a sqlline example on the calcite site. thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Below some basic code to query Cassandra through Calcite using SQL via Avatica/JDBC:

```
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:model=model.json");
     CalciteConnection calciteConnection = connection.unwrap(CalciteConnection.class);
     Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from \"test_collection\"")) {

    while (rs.next()) {
      [...]
    }
}
```

Where `model.json` is along the line of the example in the [documentation](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/cassandra_adapter.html).

If you need to use more advanced functionalities (like reasoning on query planning), you have to register your schema, in this way:

```
SchemaPlus rootSchema = calciteConnection.getRootSchema();
rootSchema.add("CASSANDRA",
               new CassandraSchema("targethostname", "mykeyspace", rootSchema, "CASSANDRA"));
```

Please note that the information provided in `CassandraSchema` must match those of `model.json`. Your queries will need to reference the schema name. So the above query must be written in this way:

```
"select * from \"cassandra\".\"test_collection\""
```